# regex unix command

Tags: regex, unix

I have this line in unix:

```
icron123:40341   [stopped]         pid:16925   /tmp/localdisk/
```

I have got a number after icron123. That means, `40341`.

What is good practice command for that?
I tried with grep, sed and tr but it very difficult and complicated.

Comment: I don't know how you made any of those complicated. Show what you tried, and explain what went wrong. Avoid being vague. And explain your expected result.

Comment: Possible dupicate of [grep for contents AFTER pattern](/questions/10358547/grep-for-contents-after-pattern)

Comment: Try this `echo 'icron123:40341 [stopped] pid:16925 /tmp/localdisk/' | sed -E 's/icron123:([0-9]*).+/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$ echo unix: icron123:40341 [stopped] pid:16925 |  grep -o "icron123:[0-9]*" | grep -o [0-9]*$
40341
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` or `pregrep` for example:

```
grep -oP "icron123:\K.+?(?=\s)" file.txt
```

or

```
pcregrep -o "icron123:\K.+?(?=\s)" file.txt
```

Both will return only `40341`

The `\K` can be read as excluding everything to the left before it and return only the right part `.+?(?=\s)` until and space `\s` is found.

You could extend it to match anything before the `\K` for example:

```
grep -oP "icron[0-9]*:\K.+?(?=\s)" file.txt
```

In this case, `icron[0-9]*:\K` will match `incronXXX:` where [`XXX`](https://regex101.com/r/zL7Qqt/1) could be any number.